# Save plot made of multiple images is turning out blank

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a features file, and I need to draw each features against each other and to separate the resulting plots into different files.

I create a `matplotlib.pyplot` plot made of multiple scatterplot:

```
length = len(FeatureNames)
nCols = 4
FigSize = 6
nRows = int(length/nCols) + (0 if length % nCols == 0 else 1)
for i in range(length):
    feature1 = FeatureNames[i]
    figs, axs = plt.subplots(ncols= nCols, nrows=nRows, figsize=(FigSize* nCols, int(FigSize*length/nCols)))
    for j in range(length):
        if i != j:
            feature2 = FeatureNames[j]
        
            X = Features[[feature1, feature2]]
        
            values = np.vstack([X[feature1], X[feature2]])
            kernel = scipy.stats.gaussian_kde(values)(values)
            plot = seaborn.scatterplot(data=X, x= feature1, y= feature2, c=kernel, cmap="viridis", ax=axs[int(j/nCols), j % nCols])
        
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig("Test " + str(i) + ".pdf", dpi=300)
    plt.savefig("Test " + str(i) + ".png", dpi=300)
    plt.cla()
```

The resulting image displayed is exactly what I expected, but the figured saved are empty... just a white/empty image.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html):

**Saving figures to file and showing a window at the same time**

If you want an image file as well as a user interface window, use `pyplot.savefig` before `pyplot.show`. At the end of (a blocking) `show()` the figure is closed and thus unregistered from pyplot. Calling `pyplot.savefig` afterwards would save a new and thus empty figure. This limitation of command order does not apply if the show is non-blocking or if you keep a reference to the figure and use `Figure.savefig`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for the PNG result, but the PDF is still empty. Any idea?

Comment: I have tried saving a dummy plot using the sequence: plt.savefig('file.png'); plt.savefig('file.pdf'); plt.show(); plt.cla() and it works fine for me, and saves both files correctly. Have you been able to figure it out? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, still does not not work, even if I precise the format, and no errors, just a blank PDF file.

Comment: It seems that 300 dpi is not supported for the PDF. I decreased it and everything went fine.